# giving rw permission to subfolders of foo folder in linux

Tags: linux, permissions

How can I give highest and lowest permission to all sub folders and files including in a folder?
I used "chmod +x" for a certain file but I don't know how to do this for all folders and files which are in the folder.

Comment: `chmod +x -R` will recursively give that permission to all the files in a folder.

Comment: thanks cnluzon , but it doesn't what i want, i changed the permission of folders and files with chmod command and put a lock on their icons . now how should I fix it?

Comment: I'm just guessing but I think you did `-r` instead of capital `-R`.  `chmod -r` removes read permission from the files and that probably is the reason why you got the lock on the icons. If this is the case, to remove that lock you need to `sudo chmod +r` to these files.

Answer (score 0):

The lock means that you don't have write access to the files in question. My guess is that you pulled your images off a cd or something, and that their ownerships/permissions are jumbled up. You may want to straighten things up. In a terminal:

### $ cd /path/to/files/

### $ su -c 'chown  *.jpg'

### $ "root's password"

**$ chmod 644 *.jpg**

I hope you'll enjoy Debian!